# how to transfer the td id value to another page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, ajax

```
 document.getElementById('scdiv').innerHTML=Quantity
<td id="scdiv"> </td>
document.getElementById('quantitydiv').innerHTML=mrp
<td id="quantitydiv"> </td>
```

Here the code is printed but i want to send the printed value of  
And  to the another page by submit button.
Please solve my problem.

Comment: Could you please elaborate a little bit? What value of what element?

Comment: Here the Values of quantity And mrp is come but i want to use these values to another page. so please tell me how it is possible ?

Answer (score 0):

you can use ajax call to send the request to another page. Grab the value in jquery or javascript and make a ajax post request to the page you want then thats it, you got the value.

Answer (score 0):

I am doing my best here, but I only partially understand what you want.

I think something like this is what you want. Keep in mind that this is terrible code and you should preferably use [cookies](http://php.net/manual/en/features.cookies.php) or [sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php)

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
     <head>
     </head>
     <body>
         <table>
             <td id="scdiv"> </td>
             <td id="quantitydiv"> </td>
         </table>

         <form action="/another-page" method="get">
             <input id="QuantityFormElement" type="hidden" name="Quantity" />
             <input id="mrpFormElement" type="hidden" name="mrp" />
             <input type="submit" value="Send" />
         </form>

         <script type="text/javascript">
         (function () {
             var Quantity = "123";
             var mrp = "123";
             document.getElementById('scdiv').innerHTML=Quantity;
             document.getElementById('quantitydiv').innerHTML=mrp;

             document.getElementById('QuantityFormElement').value=Quantity;
             document.getElementById('mrpFormElement').value=mrp;
         })()
         </script>
     </body>
```

and on the other page

```
 <?php
     echo 'Quantity: ' . htmlspecialchars($_GET["Quantity"]) . '!';
     echo "<br/>";
     echo 'mrp: ' . htmlspecialchars($_GET["mrp"]) . '!';
 ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

One of the easier ways to transfer data between pages is using a query string.  `http://yoursite.com?foo=bar`

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. Your answer is too generic to be of use here

Comment: The original question is how to transfer a value to another page.  I feel like my answer does address that.